# nsis - How to copy files through loop

Tags: installation, nsis, file-read, file-copying, line-by-line

I saved the files to be copied to a .dat file as below.

```
\Bin\a.exe
\Bin\b.dll
\Bin\c.dll
\Bin\d.dll
\Bin\e.dll
\Bin\f.dll
```

Then I want to read the .dat file line by line.
I read it by line as below code(.nsi).

```
  ClearErrors
  FileOpen $0 "CopyFileList.dat" r                    

  loop:

  FileRead $0 $1                          
  Strcmp $1 "" done
  StrCpy $varBinFileName $1
  File /r "${TARGETDIR}\$varBinFileName"             
  goto loop

  done:

  FileClose $0
```

Then two problems arise!! 
1) Read the name of the variable itself, not the stored value of the variable $varBinFileName. 
So, even though the file is there,
 The file can not be found because it is not a file name.

2) When a .dat file is read, a "||" is added. 
For example, reading the first line produces the following results: `\Bin\a.exe||` 
I want to get the result of removing "||" to use it when copying files.

Please let me know if there is a better way to read the .dat file line by line and copy it over the loop instead of the code I wrote.

Comment: Are you talking about copying files or extracting files from the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

The `File` instruction does not work like that, it does not accept variables because the filename refers to a file on the machine you are compiling on. The file is compressed and stored inside the setup .exe. Use the [`CopyFiles`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#copyfiles) instruction to copy files that are already on the end users system.

To conditionally extract something you need to write something like this:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
${If} $myvar == "something.ext"
  File "something.ext"
${Else}
  File "somethingelse.ext"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

**2)**

`FileRead` includes the newline characters (if any) and you must remove them:

```
; Write example file
FileOpen $0 "$temp\nsistest.txt" w
FileWrite $0 "hello$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 "world$\r$\n"
FileClose $0

; Parse file
FileOpen $0 "$temp\nsistest.txt" r
loop:
    FileRead $0 $1
    StrCmp $1 "" done
        StrCpy $2 $1 "" -1 ; Copy last character
        StrCmp $2 '$\r' +2
        StrCmp $2 '$\n' +1 +3
        StrCpy $1 $1 -1 ; Remove newline
        Goto -4 ; ...and check the end again
    DetailPrint line=$1
    Goto loop
done:
FileClose $0
```

Comment: Is that the only way to enter the binaries to be installed via hardcoding?

Comment: You can use `!system` to execute a batch file that generates a text file with the NSIS instructions that you can then `!include`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866848/3501 etc.

Comment: I created a batch file with reference to that link. I want to run a batch file from within the install section, but I get an error when I put that code in section. ( Error: command Section not valid in Section ) 
Is it code that can not be executed within sections or functions?

Comment: You can't put a section in a section. Do not use the exact file I linked to, just a file that writes `echo File ...`.